# Equivalences classes for modulo n

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, modular-arithmetic, proof-explanation

I have been asked to prove the following proposition:

Proposition 6.24: Fix a *modulus n* $\in$ **N**.

*i*) $\equiv$ is an equivalence relation on **Z**

*ii*) The equivalence relation $\equiv$ has exactly *n* distinct equivalence classes, namely [0],[1],...,[n-1].

I am comfortable with solving part i) of this proof, but am confused about part ii. I think my confusion stems from that I don't really understand what an equivalence class in the modulus *is*. Is it the set of integers which can be divided by a given integer? Ie- the set of integers which can be divided by *n*, if we are talking about (mod n)?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: An equivalence class is the set of integers which have the same remainder when divided by $n$.

Comment: Why is this the case? Does this imply that a~b = a-b=jn = a=jn+b, where b represents the remainder? I guess maybe I don't really understand what an equivalence class is.

Comment: It does imply what you (and actually  is logically equivalent: $a\equiv b\mod n$ means that $a$ and $b $ have the same remainder, or that $a-b$ is divisible by $n$. As a consequence,the equivalence class of $a$ is the set $\{a+kn\mid k\in\mathbf Z\}$. For instance, the class of $3\bmod 7$ is the set $\{3, 10, 17,\dots, -4,-11,-18,\dots\}$. It's like an arithmetic progression, but in both directions.

Answer (score 0):

Let $n$ be the modulus.
Let $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ be arbitrary.

By the division algorithm, there exists unique integers $a,b$ with $0 \leq b < n$ such that $k = an + b$.

Note that $k \equiv b$, as $k - b = an$ which is divisible by $n$.
Since $0 \leq b < n$, we have the desired result, as an arbitrary integer $k$ is congruent to one of $0, 1, \dots , n-1$.